# replacing current shell with execl()

Tags: shell, c, exec

In the following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int     main(void){
        char *shell = getenv("SHELL");
        execl(shell, NULL, NULL);
        perror("execl() failed");
}
```

When I run the above I find myself inside a new shell. When I type `exit` the new shell exits and I find myself back in my old shell.

Shouldn't `execl()` replace the current shell with a new shell (and not spawn a new shell inside the old shell)?

(Linux 4.16)

Comment: Not related to the question, but it should be `execl(shell, shell, (char *)NULL);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Shouldn't `execl()` replace the current shell with a new shell (and not spawn a new shell inside the old shell)?

It replaces the current process, which is the process running your program, not the shell.

When you start your program, the process tree looks like

```
old shell → your program
```

When your program calls `execl()`, that tree becomes

```
old shell → new shell
```

so when you exit the shell, you return to the old shell.

If you want to replace the old shell, you need to tell the old shell to replace itself with your new program:

```
exec ./yourprogram
```

Then your program will replace itself with the new shell, and you’ll have replaced the old shell with the new one (with an extra step involving your program).

Comment: got it thanks! Is there any way via C to replace the grand-parent process so-to-speak?

Comment: There’s no reliable way: one process isn’t supposed to be able to modify another (including replacing it). You *can* use interfaces designed for debuggers (`ptrace` etc.) to cause another process to call a function such as `execl()` (in the same way you can by connecting `gdb` to a running process).